# Object is not being returned the same

Tags: c++11

When I add a custom class object into a queue, and get it back by remove. The contents of the object is changed. 
For example, I set the priority of the shopper to 10, then I add it to the queue, then remove it and check the priority again, which doesn't return 10. This works perfectly with other data types like int. Not sure why it is not working with the type. Any possible source of error?

```
//main.cpp
PriorityQueueSearch<Shopper> b;
Shopper temp(10);
b.add(temp);
Shopper removed = b.remove();
std::cout<<removed.getPriority();
```

Comment: Yes, there are many possible sources of error. We can't guess and help you, since we have no idea what `PriorityQueueSearch` and `Shopper` are.  Please try to reduce your problem to a [mcve] and paste that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying to help. PriorityQueueSearch was just a subclass of array implementation of queue (ArrayQueue class). And Shopper was just class with random priority as one of its variables.

The error was in the overloaded operator. Apparently, I was overloading the assignment operator (=), when I wanted to overload the comparison operator(==). Adding that extra '=' to the function prototype got rid of the problem.

Advice to myself would be is to pay closer attention to what I am typing.